# SuiteTalk and timezone inconsistency

Tags: c#, web-services, timezone, netsuite

I do a search via SuiteTalk and get a single record with lastModifiedDate:

```
<listRel:lastModifiedDate>2014-12-12T11:12:24.000-08:00</listRel:lastModifiedDate>
```

I updated this record at 19:12:24 UK time so I know the lastModifiedDate is correct.

In my C# code I read the lastModifiedDate value, which gets me 12/12/2014 19:12:24 when I ToString the lastModifiedDate DateTime value.

Then I modify a record so that its lastModifiedDate is changed to now.

Then I perform another search, this time specifying the previous lastModifiedDate value in the search criteria.

The generated request XML looks like this:

```
        <q1:lastModifiedDate operator="notBefore">
            <searchValue xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">2014-12-12T19:12:24</searchValue>
        </q1:lastModifiedDate>
```

There are no response records.

This, I presume, is because the SuiteTalk assumes that 2014-12-12T19:12:24 is the same as 2014-12-12T19:12:24-08:00, which is in the future and certainly after the moment I updated the record a minute ago.

So how can I make SuiteTalk know what time I mean?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to include offset in the generated value.  Can you show your C# code?

Comment: @MattJohnson How can I get the offset from a DateTime variable?

Comment: I am interacting with web reference code generated by Visual Studio from a WSDL file. I am setting a DateTime property in that generated code and the value of this DateTime property is being written to the XML document that is sent as the request to SuiteTalk.

Comment: This article explains more: https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteCloudCustomizationScriptingWebServices/SuiteTalkWebServices/BuiltinTypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would interact with a `DateTimeOffset` type, so there was no confusion.

However, since you said you are interacting with code generated from a WSDL, and you can't change the WSDL or the code it generates, then you must interact with a `DateTime` type.  When doing so, be sure you the `.Kind` property to `DateTimeKind.Utc` so that the time is shifted to UTC and when serialized to ISO8601 format, the xml will include the `Z` character at the end.

Assuming your original values are in the local time of the computer you are running on:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,12,12,19,12,24);
foo.LastModifiedDate = dt.ToUniversalTime();
```

Or, if you are working with a particular time zone, you can do something like this instead:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,12,12,19,12,24);
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
foo.LastModifiedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tzi);
```

Comment: So you're saying that calling ToUniversalTime() sets the Kind property to DateTimeKind.Utc?

Comment: Yes, and adjusts the value to UTC also.